# How to get the X and Y axis of a string or a paragraph from a PDF file?

Tags: php, jquery, html, pdf, vtiger

I am making a module for a system called vtiger CRM, for this system I have a module installed called `PDFMaker` which allows me to make PDF files using HTML, PDFMaker also allows me to create custom function to insert in the template.

I currently have a custom function, which puts a string called `signature` in the HTML template.

What I need is to find the X and Y axis of the string after it has been converted to a PDF file due to the dimension changing when it gets converted from a HTML template to a PDF file.

What I tried was using the `.position` function from jQuery, but the problem with that is, is that it works with a HTML file, but it doesn't work with a PDF file, with makes sense.

Now I am wondering how I can find the X and Y axis from a paragraph or string in a PDF file.

The PDF files that created are for example invoices, quotes and things like that, normally they are A4 paper format, but that may vary.

This is my custom function at this moment:

```
<?php
    if(!function_exists('signature')){
        function signature($string = 'Signature'){
            $xAxis = '<script>
                $(function(){
                    var p = $("#signature");
                    var position = p.position();
                    document.write(position.left);
                });
            </script>';
            $yAxis = '<script>
                $(function(){
                    var p = $("#signature");
                    var position = p.position();
                    document.write(position.top);
                });
            </script>';

            return $xAxis . ' ' . $yAxis;
        }
    }
?>
```

It does not return anything to the PDF file.

Comment: post your custom functions! how are we supposed to know anything, if we don't know the pdf library used ?

Comment: I added it, although I doubt it will help much.

Comment: it doesn't but now i can see it ;)
You will have to look at the function which converts the html template to a pdf. Why do you even Need the Position of it ?

Comment: I need the location for an API I am using from Docusign, which is a application which allows people to sign documents digitally. I can't look into the function which converts it due to it being a licensed product and not being able to change any of the source code.

Comment: ouch ... i hope somebody will give you an usefull answer. only possibility i see is to generate the pdf,use OCR for finding the Position of the string (which is a pain for itself) and then use this. 
Or do a static Position for each template (if possible).
Maybe your pdf module gives you a possiblity to do it better, but i can't tell from here.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo It indeed it a pretty hard problem to solve, thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106592/discussion-between-doktor-oswaldo-and-tom).

Answer (score 0):

You will have to calculate it.
First you have to find out how many Pixels there are used in the pdf. (Depending on the DPI of the PDF).

Let's call this pdf_width (x) and pdf_height (y)

Second you Need to find the Maximum used width of the template. I saw that your template get's it's width reduced to fit on the page. You can find that out, by getting the Position.right of an element which is as far right as possible.
Let's call this max_template_x.

Now wee Need the length of the Signature text:

```
var length = p.position().right - p.position().left;
```

Then the real Position on the Template:

```
if (p.position().right > max_template_x) {
posX = max_template_x - length}
```

Then multiply it with the template to pdf quota:

```
posX = posX * (pdf_width / template_max_x)
```

Now you have the x.

For the y you have to do the same, only with pagebrake and depending of the amount of text you put above the signature.

Comment: There is no such thing as .position.right, so this won't work.

Comment: wrap the text in a span and use .width()

Comment: The amount of pixels used in a PDF changes depending on what the person uses for its format.